# How to linearize such a constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, binary-variable

My original content was like this:

Assuming that server $k$ can only allocate corresponding computing functions to MU $i$ after receiving their tasks. Let

$$ y_{i,k,t} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if MU $i$ has sent a task to server $k$ at time slot $t$} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Therefore, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
   y_{i,k,t} \leq s_{i, k,t},  \quad \forall i,k,t. 
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
    y_{i,k,t} \geq x_{i,k,t}, \quad \forall i,k,t.
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{equation}
x_{i,k,t} \geq y_{i,k,t} + s_{i,k,t} - 1. \quad \forall i,k,t. \label{3_start}
\end{equation}

where

- $s_{i, k, t}$ denotes whether the user $i$ is transferring tasks to the server $k$ at time slot $t$
- $x_{i, k, t}$ denotes whether the server $k$ is allocating resources to the user $i$ at time slot $t$.

I want to constrain the server to only start allocating resources to users after receiving their task requests. However, now I want to change this constraint to that users may need more than one time slot to send tasks. How should I change this constraint?

Comment: Would you please, what conditional expressions you have tried to write? (e.g. if x=1 then y=1), etc.

Comment: Original content of what? What does MU stand for?